# numpyを使わずに多次元配列の列の抽出

Tags: python, python3, numpy

numpyを使わずにコードが1行ぐらいで収まり速度も速い
列の抽出をしたいと考えています。

と、言いますのも
https://x1.inkenkun.com/archives/861
こちらの記事など他にもかなり調べてみたのですが
配列・要素の挿入・削除等の基本的な計算は
numpyを使わない方が速度が速いようです。
np.dot や np.exp(-x) の時はコードが見やすくて助かるのですが

numpyを使わずに列の抽出ができないとなれば
for文で1つずつ要素を新しい配列に追加していくしかないのかなと
考えています。

解決策でなくとも、みなさんなりのご意見がございましたら頂戴したいです。
なにとぞ、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 問題が抽象的だと思います。stackoverflowは原則として計算機にて解決したい問題を提示し解決策を探索する場であると思います。さらに列の抽出という唯一の目的意識からは、要素の挿入及び削除という話が見えてきません。おそらく単なる列の抽出ならnumpyのほうが速いですよ。

Answer (score 2):

jupyter notebook を使うとコードの実行時間を簡単に計ることができます。
numpyの配列を使った方が遥かに速いです。

```
n = 1000000

%timeit xs = [i for i in range(n)]
10 loops, best of 3: 70.3 ms per loop

%timeit xs = [None] * n
100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

import numpy as np

%timeit a = np.arange(n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop

%timeit a = np.zeros(n)
The slowest run took 5.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 456 µs per loop
```

jupyter notebookをインストールするのが面倒な場合は [Google Colabotry](https://colab.research.google.com/) が、無料ですぐに使えます。

Answer (score 0):

numpyのndarrayを配列として使うのは一般的です。
numpyを使わない場合、nested listで配列を表します。

Pythonの基本オブジェクトを処理する場合、cytoolzは早いと思います。
例えば：

```
import cytoolz
a = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6], 
     [7, 8, 9], 
     [11, 12, 13]]
list(cytoolz.pluck(1, a))
[2, 5, 8, 12]

list(cytoolz.pluck([1, 2], a))
[(2, 3), (5, 6), (8, 9), (12, 13)]
```

Comment: cytoolz というのもあるのですか、
ますますどうしたらよいかという感じですが
教えていただいてありがとうございます。